# create database nhibernate fluent asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, fluent-nhibernate

how i can create database in sql server by nhibernate fluent. i use this code:

```
        string server = "localhost\\SQLEXPRESS";
        string database = "NameDb";
        const string user = "admin";
        const string password = "admin";

            var connectionString = string.Format("Server={0};Database={1};User Id={2};Password={3};",
                                                 server, database, user, password);
            var autoMap = AutoMap.AssemblyOf<AggregateBase>()
                .Where(t => typeof(AggregateBase).IsAssignableFrom(t));

            SessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(connectionString))
                .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(autoMap))
                .ExposeConfiguration(TreatConfiguration)
                .BuildSessionFactory();

 protected  static void TreatConfiguration(NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration configuration)
        {
            var update = new  SchemaUpdate(configuration);
            update.Execute(false, true);
        }
```

but it creates just the schema, if there is no namedb in sql server did not generate the database

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate can't create the database automatically. You'll have to do it yourself.